# python paramiko shell commands

Tags: python, shell, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to compile a program on a server. As you may know it compiling takes a lot of time and a lot of data is being sent out from this process. Since I cannot get from a shell command the exit status of the command to be executed I'm forced to wait for the data to be sent out to me and, when it stops sending, I can move on to the next command in line.

This practice is not reliable because of some issues:
 - the program may still execute without sending output
 - I have to use sleep commands if `recv_ready` returns false in order to keep my memory low
 - using sleep commands is time consuming given the fact that I don't know how much to "sleep" it before considering the process as done so I can move on to the next one

Here's my actual code so far:

```
for command in commands:
    shell.send( "%s\n" % command )
    waited = 0
    while True:
        if shell.recv_ready():
            x = shell.recv( 1024 )
            if len( x ):
                print x
                shell.settimeout( 1 )
                waited = 0
        else:
            time.sleep( 1 )
            waited += 1
            if waited > 10:
                break
```

This is working fine for most cases but if the running task lasts longer than 10 seconds my program moves to the next command because he thinks it's done. If I increase the timeout threshold to say 20 seconds I lose 20 seconds between each command being executed which is a lot of time wasted considering the fact that most commands take less than 1-2 seconds to execute.

How do you guys suggest i should do this?

Comment: Have you considered using [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect)?

Comment: I agree, pexpect is better suited tool for these kind of tasks

Comment: So I should go for pexpect and wait for `pexpect.EOF` instead right?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't get the exit status. [`fabric`](http://fabfile.org/) might be simpler to use.

Comment: because in shell mode the exit status is not the exit status of the process but the one of the shell. Fabric website says that also.

Comment: Do you have to reuse a single shell? Have you considered using `exec_command()`, which gives a clear indication of an exit code? You would also need not worry about timeouts, and you can get separate stdout and stderr streams.

Comment: can we see the server side?